# Strip Out All Unwanted Characters

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, strip-tags

I am using the following code to strip out unwanted characters but it is not stripping out everything and throwing a MySQL error:

```
    $commentmessage = strip_tags($commentmessage);
    $commentmessage = htmlentities($commentmessage, ENT_QUOTES);
```

What code would I use to strip out anything that might cause a MySQL error?

The message I am receiving is:

Error message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'omg thats the one". One of the logo's we really liked was 1049859 where the f' at line 2**

Comment: Prepared statement maybe?

Comment: Which [MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) are you using: [ext/mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php); [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php); or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?

Comment: I am using a prepared statement with the PDO API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evidently you're building your query like so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('$bar')";
```

which is breaking because the text of `$bar` contains single quotes. `'`

*No.* *hits you with a rolled-up newspaper* *Bad developer.*

I *could* just throw you a string escaping function, or I could show you to do it right like:

```
$bar = "I am a problematic string!'; DROP TABLE USERS -- "
$query = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($bar));
```

Or:

```
$bar = "I am a problematic string!'; DROP TABLE USERS -- "
$query = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (:bar)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array('bar'=>$bar));
```

When you prepare a query like this PHP/PDO/MySQL get together and pre-agree on what types your placeholders are. So your strings are treated like strings without the need for escaping characters. This both prevents rogue single quotes from breaking your query, and help protect you from SQL injection attacks.

You can also re-use prepared statements to increase performance: [relative to un-prepared statements since the SQL only needs to be parsed once, rather than once per query]

```
$query = "INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
foreach( $bars as $bar ) {
  $stmt->execute(array($bar));
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. He searches for a way to strip out the characters, not just escape them.

Comment: @laubed then *you* write an answer that addresses the symptoms, I'll keep my answer as-is to address the underlying cause.

Comment: Im not saying that the answer is not correct, just saying that it doesn't match the question. 
I think the problem is in the question itself. But to give an answer that evaluates allowed inputs its necessary to know the use case. Would suggest a simple alphanumerical(+puncutation) regexp for a more general approach

Comment: @laubed: My reading is that the asker was attempting to "strip unwanted characters" due to a lack of understanding about string escaping / SQL parameterisation: I suspect that this is what the asker was really after.

Comment: @eggyal I already upvoted and i agree that this answer is the way to go